# How to set a build property (the `-P` commandline argument) to null in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, gradle-properties

When I execute gradle with the following command:

```
./gradlew publishToMavenLocal -PsplainVersion=null
```

I got the following error:

```
...
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':graph-commons:scalaCompilerPlugins'.
   > Could not resolve io.tryp:splain_2.13.6:null.
```

It appears that null is not parsed properly as a control token, instead it becomes a string. Is there a method to help Gradle to understand it as a real null value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradle will effectively treat anything as an argument of some kind. There is no null checking whatsoever.

So if you need to ensure a null argument is not given to your build script, then you need to validate the argument is not null where it is being used.

```
tasks.register("verifyNonNull") {
    onlyIf {
        property("splainVersion") != 'null'
    }
}
```

If you are curious of Gradle's logic, check out the source of [`CommandLineParser`](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/v7.2.0/subprojects/cli/src/main/java/org/gradle/cli/CommandLineParser.java).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm using kts variant so it's probably easier to switch to the non-monadic type (so it is either empty or a value, but cannot be null)